# Is these equations generalizable for R^n?

Tags: linear-algebra

The representation of the $\mathbb{R}$ set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a line that have the general equation $ax+by=c$.

The representation of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a plane that have the general equation $ax+by+cz=d$.

It seems adding one dimension and scaling it by a escalar always gives me the previous biggest possible set, is this true?

Is the representation of the $\mathbb{R}^3$ set in $\mathbb{R}^4$ the space that have $ax+by+cz+d\alpha=e$ as equation?

In other words, $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw intuition is fine, but it depends on what you mean by 'representation'. You are right in that the linear equation $$a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b$$ with at least one $a_i \neq 0$ defines an affine hyperplane which is indeed an '$(n-1)$-dimensional space' of sorts. One way to motivate this notion of dimensionality is that if you choose $n-1$ of the variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, say without loss of generality the first $n-1$, i.e. $x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}$, then the last variable $x_n$, provided $a_n \neq 0$, is fully determined. (Hence in the sense $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $n$ 'free' variables the solution space to that linear equation above has $n-1$ 'free' variables.)

In the specific case $b = 0$ the solutions to a linear equation defines an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for instance by the rank-nullity theorem, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. (This you can see by change of basis.) But in the case $b \neq 0$ you do not have a linear subspace at all; the sum of two points on the line $ax + by = c$ with $c \neq 0$ is not another solution to $ax + by = c$. Thus if $b \neq 0$ your solution space is not $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ in the sense it does not have addition. (Nor, for that matter, does it have scalar multiplication)

In other words, if your idea of 'representation of', which I suspect is code for 'has the same structure as', is equality at the level of vector spaces, then what you've said is not correct since your solution space (to the linear equation) doesn't need to (when $b \neq 0$) have addition or scalar multiplication. It's true they are 'equal' as affine spaces (or even as topological spaces), which I believe is what you are thinking of when you say $\mathbb{R}$ is 'represented' by a line.